# How to image and deploy a Bootcamp setup?

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, startup, disk-utility

We are rolling out iMac's and MacBook Pro's throughout the business and are setting them up with Boot Camp and an option to boot into Windows 7.  Essentially the partition is just split down the middle, one for OSX and the other for Windows.

Now I want to be able to deploy this setup easily throughout the business by creating a complete disk image and then transferring it to the other machines.  for example there is software on each partition that I want to install and config changes to make then I just want to image the whole lot and deploy it to all of the other Mac's.  We used to do something similar just with PC's and Windows using software like Ghost or Acronis True Image but I am just unsure of how we can do it with Mac?

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a paid software called Winclone. It's at version 3.7 now. Take a look at reviews to see if it will do what you want. There is another open source software but I can't recall the name now. You might run into that info while doing a search for Winclone.

http://twocanoes.com/winclone/

Comment: Thanks.  Will have a look at Winclone and see how we go.